# Does declaring (foreach loop) iterator upfront affect the performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach

Consider a `Gridview` with 1000 rows.

If I want to iterate through each row of the gridview, I can do that in two ways:

```
foreach (GridviewRow row in gridview1.Rows) {
    // the variable row is declared in the body of the for loop.
    // do stuff with current row
}
```

Another way is :

```
GridviewRow row;

foreach(row in gridview1.Rows) {
    // here, the variable row was declared before for loop.
    // do stuff with current row.
}
```

I would like to know if both of them will is "better" than the other in terms of memory allocation/cpu performance, etc.

Comment: How bout simply trying both and inspecting the generated IL? I'm not really sure what could be minimally worrying you about the efficiency differences, if any, between one or the other...

Comment: What I meant is: is it better if I use one way or the other? edited my question to clear up the confusion. @InBetween

Comment: Performance?  Well prior to .NET 4 a simple `foreach` produces boxing garbage which was a huge blow to XNA; Mono and Unity3D.  Unity only [recently solved this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization/optimizing-garbage-collection-unity-games).  You may want to consider just using a `for` loop depending on your .NET version

Comment: _"...in terms of memory allocation/cpu performance..."_ -  sometimes you can't have both.  A mere lookup-table algorithm might use alot of memory but is blazingly fast.   Sometimes its faster to unwind a tight loop to get around the overhead of a BNE; BLE; JCC or whatever the equivalent assembler is in today's CPUs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about generated IL code but don't see any difference between the two posted approach considering the fact that you are using `foreach` loop here and not `for` loop.

Comment: I have edited my question to make my query more clear.

Comment: @Ahmad, as mentioned in answer ... there is no difference